# Which mirror should I use to download Kernel Xen 6.3?

Tags: virtualization, xen, centos6, rpm, repository

I'm following [this construction](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-xen-on-centos-6.2-x86_64-paravirtualization-and-hardware-virtualization) to install (version 4.1.2) on a CentOS 6.2 (x86_64) system.
When I use this command

```
yum install http://au1.mirror.crc.id.au/repo/kernel-xen-release-6-3.noarch.rpm
```

I face this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.sh.cvut.cz
 * extras: ftp.sh.cvut.cz
 * updates: ftp.sh.cvut.cz
Setting up Install Process
Cannot open: http://au1.mirror.crc.id.au/repo/kernel-xen-release-6-3.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
Error: Nothing to do
```

there is a  [third-party repository](https://www.crc.id.au/repo/) with some mirror list, but I don't know if I could use them? and how would that possible?
I would appreciate if any one could lead me to a available link to download Xen Repository.

Comment: Have you tried these? http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/RHEL6_Xen4_Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You received the error because the file does not exist.

The reason the file does not exist is that [the file in the repo](http://au1.mirror.crc.id.au/repo/) is named `kernel-xen-release-6-4.noarch.rpm`, while your howto has a `3` instead of the `4`.